# Format text that is splitted accross span that aren't on the same level

Tags: css, word-wrap, line-breaks

I have the following HTML structure that I can't change:

```css
.parent {
  width: 250px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px dotted;
  text-align: right;
}
span,
.contenteditable {
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="contenteditable">
      <span>Some text that is the first part of the sentence</span>
  </div>
  <span>and this is the second part</span>
</div>
```

So the two span are not on the same level, yet they are part of the same text. Because of this, a line break is always inserted before the last span, but I'd like the text to behave like a single chunk of text, i.e.:

```
Some text that is the first part of the
   sentence and this is the second part
```

instead of:

```
Some text that is the first part of the
                               sentence 
            and this is the second part
```

Is this achievable using CSS only ?

Comment: `display:inline` instead of `display:inline-block`

Comment: Thank you @GabrielePetrioli, you're absolutely right that did the trick! If you want to post your comment as an answer i'll mark it as accepted. Thanks Again !